# Update MongoDB array field value using value of another field

Tags: mongodb

I know it's possible to update specific array elements, as documented here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

Also, I'm aware it's possible to use a field value to update the value of another field, as explained here: [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

What I need is a combination of the two.

Let's say I have this in the DB:

```
{
  a: [
     {
        aa: 10
     },
     {
        cc: 15
     }

  ]
}
```

Now, I want to add a field `bb` to the array documents with `aa`'s value, but only if `aa` exists. So the output is:

```
{
  a: [
     {
        aa: 10,
        bb: 10
     },
     {
        cc: 15
     }

  ]
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like you should make a filter that finds all documents having the 'aa' and use that list for the update. I.e. look at [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#mongodb-method-db.collection.updateMany)

Comment: Why aggregation update you referred doesn't work for you? You can use all aggregation functions within the $set.

Comment: @AlexBlex I needed a way to update only specific elements in the array matching a certain filter. The arrayFilters is not supported in the aggregation syntax. Apparently what I needed is $map per turivishal answer.

Comment: @JHBonarius this is not enough, I needed to update specific elements in aa according to a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- match field exists a condition
- `$map` to iterate loop of `a` array
- `$cond` check condition if `aa` field is not null then add new field `bb` with value of `aa` and merge with current object using `$mergeObjects`, otherwise return current object

```
db.collection.update(
  { "a.aa": { $exists: true } },
  [{
    $set: {
      a: {
        $map: {
          input: "$a",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $ne: ["$$this.aa", null] },
              { $mergeObjects: ["$$this", { bb: "$$this.aa" }] }
              "$$this",
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }],
  { multi: true }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BTn3mJflGfr)