# How to update a field of array's element using aggregate pipeline

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB v4.2.13. I have a collection `Transaction` with documents like this:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "product": [
        {
            "name": "Book",
            "price": 100
        },
        {
            "name": "Pen",
            "price": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to add a new field `paid` into the first element of `product`, which equal it's `price`.

```json
{
    "name": "Book",
    "price": 100,
    "paid": 100
}
```

I try to use updating with aggregate pipeline `$addFields`/`$set`, but result is not as expected.

Query (I only want to use **one query**):

```js
db.Transaction.updateOne(
    { id: 1 },
    [
        {
            $addFields: {
                "product.0.paid": {
                    $arrayElemAt: ["$product.price", 0]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Expected result:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "product": [
        {
            "name": "Book",
            "price": 100,
            "paid": 100
        },
        {
            "name": "Pen",
            "price": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

Actual result:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "product": [
        {
            "name": "Book",
            "price": 100,
            "0" : {
                "paid" : 100
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Pen",
            "price": 10,
            "0" : {
                "paid" : 100
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How to get the expected result?

Comment: so you want to update product named Book? how to identify which element

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67787485/update-mongodb-array-field-value-using-value-of-another-field helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution , when you dont know in advance the value of price , but you need to update only the first array element with product.0.paid:"$product.0.price"

```
 db.collection.update({},
 [
 {
  $set: {
  p1: {
    $arrayElemAt: [
      "$product",
       0
     ]
    }
   }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "p1.paid": "$p1.price"
    }
  },
 {
  $project: {
    product: {
      $concatArrays: [
      [
        "$p1"
      ],
      {
        "$slice": [
          "$product",
          1,
          {
            $size: "$product"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
 }
}
])
```

Explained:

1. Get 1st element from product array and assign to p1 temporary variable.
2. Set the paid value in p1 equal to price value from p1.
3. Concatenate product array removing old 1st element with with the newly formed p1 object.
   ( projecting only product you remove the p1 temporary variable)

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9f9j8PdmpHx)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use update/arrayFilters , you dont need to use aggregate for this task:

```
db.collection.update({"product.0.price":100},
{
 $set: {
   "product.$[x].paid": 100
 }
 },
 {
  arrayFilters: [
  {
    "x.price": 100
  }
 ]
})
```

[Playground(arrayFilters)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kIp9-hjICyJ)

Here is option with aggregate:

```
db.collection.update({
  "product.0.price": 100
},
[
{
"$addFields": {
  "product": {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$product",
      "as": "p",
      "in": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$p",
          {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$p.price",
                  100
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "paid": "$$p.price"
              },
              "else": {}
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    }
   }
  }
 ])
```

[Playground2(aggregate)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lpQm1c4vw1N)

If you need to update only 1st element in array it is even simpler:

```
  db.collection.update({
    "product.0.price": 100
  },
  {
   $set: {
   "product.0.paid": 100
   }
 })
```

[Playground(simple positional update)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/55e2gQ7rExO)

Comment: maybe he doesnt want to hardcode the 100. don't kwo for sure

Comment: @cmgchess : "which equal it's price"  -> I guess this is the expected condition , but this can be variable  in arrayFilters and in aggregation if needed ...

Comment: @R2D2 Yep, i mean i would add new field `paid` with value equals `price`'s value to the first element of `product`. I modified my query, it should be: `$arrayElemAt: ["$product.price", 0]`

Comment: check 3th playground in my answer , maybe something like this?